# Horizontal Bar Graph in C Without the Use of Arrays or Strings

Tags: c

I have a C programming assignment that I am working on currently that asks us to write a program that reads 5 numbers representing pounds of a crop harvested and then displays a bar graph representing those values. I have to use a for, while, and a do while statement to do this. I am not allowed to use graphics, arrays, or commands that analyze strings.

Here is a sample of the output that I need to replicate:

```
    Pounds of Beans: 1
    Pounds of Carrots: 2
    Pounds of Lettuce: 3
    Pounds of Peas: 4
    Pounds of Squash: 5

    Beans:   B
    Carrots: CC
    Lettuce: LLL
    Peas:    PPPP
    Squash:  SSSSS
```

I was able to successfully take the 5 inputs. My problem starts with the proper syntax and flow structure that will allow me to print the bar graph as needed. I am currently able to print the bar graph properly for the first crop but how to do that recursively for each crop is very confusing to me. Please explain the flow that I need to understand in order to properly execute this program, any syntactical errors that I am making, and what exactly is meant by "guarding".

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    // Initialize main
    int main(void)
    {

    // Introduce variables

    int count,      b, c, l, p, s;

    // Prompts & obtaining of pounds of crops
    printf("Pounds of Beans: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Pounds of Carrots: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("Pounds of Lettuce: ");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    printf("Pounds of Peas: ");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    printf("Pounds of Squash: ");

    // Print empty line between input and output
    printf("\n");

    // Precursory print of "Beans:"
    printf("Beans:   ");

    // Display pounds of beans using for statment
    for (count=0; count<b; count++)
            {
                    printf("%.*s", b, "B");
            }
            printf("\n");

    printf("Carrots: ");

    // Display lbs of carrots using for statment
    for (count=0; count<c; count++);
            {
                    printf("%.*s", c, "C");
            }
            printf("\n");

    }
```

I am currently getting errors:

```
    graph.c:44:2: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
    for (count=0; count<c; count++);
    ^~~
    graph.c:45:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘for’
    {
    ^
```

Any help that you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the stray semicolon after the `for` statement on that line.

Comment: You're using strings.

Comment: Yes I know that I am using strings to display the necessary lines. However, I am not allowed to use any commands that analyze strings like stringlength for example.

Comment: I was able to get the entire program working but only using [for] statements. Any suggestions on how to incorporate the [while] and [do while] statements?

Answer (score 1):

My version. Tell me, if you need comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void obtain_crop(char *str, int *num) {
    printf("Pounds of %-10s", str);
    scanf("%d", num);
}

void print_bar(char *name, char *ch, int num) {
    printf("%-10s", name);
    while(num > 0) {
        printf("%s", ch);
        num--;
    }   
    puts("");
}

int main() {
    int b, c, l, p, s;

    obtain_crop("Beans:", &b);
    obtain_crop("Carrots:", &c);
    obtain_crop("Lettuce:", &l);
    obtain_crop("Peas:", &p);
    obtain_crop("Squash:", &s);

    puts("");

    print_bar("Beans:", "B", b); 
    print_bar("Carrots:", "C", c); 
    print_bar("Lettuce:", "L", l); 
    print_bar("Peas:", "P", p); 
    print_bar("Squash:", "S", s); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Testing**

```
Pounds of Beans:    8
Pounds of Carrots:  6
Pounds of Lettuce:  1
Pounds of Peas:     4
Pounds of Squash:   9

Beans:    BBBBBBBB
Carrots:  CCCCCC
Lettuce:  L
Peas:     PPPP
Squash:   SSSSSSSSS
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me give you some advice: **Whenever you have any recurring operation, it should probably be a method**

Now, here is a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_value(const char * name, int * value) {
  printf("Pounds of %s: ", name);
  scanf("%d", value);
}

int draw_value(const char * name, char c, int value) {
  printf("%-*s", 10, name);
  for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    printf("%c", c);
  printf("\n");
}

// Initialize main
int main(void)
{
  // Introduce variables

  int b, c, l, p, s;

  // Prompts & obtaining of pounds of crops
  read_value("Beans", &b);
  read_value("Carrots", &c);
  read_value("Lettuce", &l);
  read_value("Peas", &p);
  read_value("Squash", &s);

  // Print empty line between input and output
  printf("\n");

  draw_value("Beans:", 'B', b);
  draw_value("Carrots:", 'C', c);
  draw_value("Lettuce:", 'L', l);
  draw_value("Peas:", 'P', p);
  draw_value("Squash:", 'S', s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example of I'm starting to understand how it all comes together.